# Get distinct data in complex join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following 3 tables:

**Job Master :**

[image]

**Ink_ProductionJobs :**

[image]

**Client Master :**

[image]

I just wanted to get all the data from ink_Productionjobs table and ClientMaster table against distinct PJobID in Jobmaster table where Isdelivered in ink_Productionjobs='Y'.

For that i made following query:

```
select distinct(jm.PJobID),jm.PDescription,ink.ClientServingUser, ink.EDateTime,ink.DDateTime ,  cm.ClientID  
from JobMaster JM 
inner join Ink_ProductionJobs Ink
on jm.PJobID=ink.pJobID 
inner join clientMaster CM
on cm.ClientID = jm.ClientID 
where IsDelivered='Y'
```

But its not showing me data against distinct pjobid in job master, instead, it is repeating pjobid.

Please help me.

Comment: try this: GROUP BY jm.PJobID : before where clause

Comment: how can group by be written before where?

Comment: on cm.ClientID = jm.ClientID 
GROUP BY jm.PJobID
where IsDelivered='Y'

Comment: not working... i checked

Comment: i think remove braces :distinct jm.PJobID   or try group by clause after where clause

Answer (score 1):

That's happen because you left jm.description out of that distinct, if the description is different for each id, the select ill return a different row.

Comment: i removed jm.description from query, but its still repeating

Comment: remove the parentesis and the jm.PJobID. Remember, the distinct clause  ill "hide" repeated rows. If rows are different in any way they ill show up. If you want just one ocurrence of jm.PJobID with many ocurrences of ProductionJpbs it's not disctinct what do you want.

Comment: By the way I realized, maybe, you are thinking that parentisis refers to the distinct clause. Maybe this article can clarify it for you http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/12/sql-distinct-group-by.aspx